# Application setup similar to REST

Tags: php, ajax, rest, web

I am setting up a system which will take requests, query a database and provide a response (in its simplest form).

The setup will be as follows.

A client. @ www.example-client.com
A server. @ www.example-api.com

The client will make a Ajax request to the server. The server will authenticate the origin. Query the DB and provide a response.

What methods should I look into for me to authenticate, server/api side that the request has come from www.example-client.com.

I understand this is / is similar to a RESTful api.  However I do not really require for the client to login. It will all valid requests will only come from www.example-client.com.

In the future they may come from mobile apps ect. However this does not need to be dynamically validated.

Thank you

If it is marked as duplicate and already answered. Could you kindly provide a link.

Much appreciated.

Comment: simplest way is have the client send token\password with every request. has a few holes, may not be safe enough for an Ajax request

Comment: Yes I thought of this. However the issue is anyone can look at the JS and see the token\password being sent.

Comment: proxy it, send request to local script that makes the request externally. if you don't use https, there are man in the middle issues

Comment: Thank you however I'd prefer not to take this route. I want to keep client side simple as possible. Ajax requests directly to the API, ideally. Anyone could call the local script.

Comment: anything in your ajax request is visible, this is a bad idea.

Comment: Regardless of if it's a bad idea or not. I'm simply asking for insight into what server side methods I can invoke to authenticate that the request came from a predefined client(s).